# collecting result of exec in some variable in sybase

Tags: t-sql, sybase

How to collect the result of exec(some_dynamic_query) statement in some variable?  This is my code snippet

**exec('Select count(*) from'+@tabname)**

where table name is fetched by a cursor into a variable and the above statement is inside a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://database.itags.org/sybase/66687/
for sample.